# Validating Firebase JWTs manually - cert expiry and finding out which one to use

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-iam

I'm able to generate custom token JWTs (verified by my service account public certs) and then obtain ID tokens as well from the SDK (verified by Google's public certs).

In the custom token JWT, the header doesn't contain the key ID - does this mean I'll just have to trial and error all three shown in my service account's cert link?

And for both the custom token and ID token, how often do the certs change? This will determine how long I can cache a cert file locally.

Comment: Yes, you need to include the private key ID in the JWT header. How are you signing the JWT? Yourself using a service account private key or via an IAM API call?

Comment: I'm only asking about verifying the JWT. The tokens generated are either using the SDK or using HTTP calls, or completely locally, and currently are identical.

Comment: To verify a JWT requires the public key. Each method of signing has a different method of obtaining the public key. On my website, I have written articles on signing, JWTs, verification, etc. I just wrote one that goes into detail about signing using PHP and dissects the PHP SDK but those techniques apply to any language. I have other articles in Python. I wrote another article on Azure/Microsoft which shows additional technical details.

Comment: @JohnHanley I know that - the public keys for the ID tokens are Google's generally, and for custom tokens are my service account's specifically. I'm asking about 1. the specific behaviour for custom tokens where my service account's public key resource shows 3 keys, only 1 of which will be correct but the custom token itself doesn't seem to say which key. 2. How often do Google's general public keys for ID tokens change

Comment: A service account is not a key. A service account is an identity. Under a service account, you can create up to 10 keys (there is another hidden key that Google uses to sign using your service account's identity). Each key has a private key ID. I commented under this question's answer for how often Google generates new Google signing keys. IIRC it is five days. Google does not rotate your service account keys - you must do that manually. I do not know how often Google rotates the hidden key attached to your service account.

Comment: In your question, you say **custom token**. Are you creating the token or are you using the Google SignJWT API call? You prefer to leave out the details that are required to give you solid answers.

Comment: If you are creating the JWT, then it is up to you to include the Key ID in the header. If Google creates the JWT, then the JWT header includes the Key ID. If you are using the SignBlob API, then you must future out which Key ID is used. The API returns the Key ID used to sign the data blob. This means sign some garbage data, grab the Key ID nd then include the Key ID in your JWT header and sign the real JWT.